# Referencing, accessing a dictionary for data

Tags: c#, dictionary, data-structures, key-value, libusb

My program is using LibUSB to communicate with a USB device, which has buttons and LEDs, which is used to send info to the device and read info from the device. The communication is done in byte arrays, up to 1024 long, but pretty much only the first 8 bytes matter. When reading, we read the byte array, and I want to display which button was pressed or LED was lit up. So, I figured a Dictionary was the best solution to use - string value for the name of the button or LED, and byte array for the key. Or possibly the reversed; the string being the key and the array being the value.

```
public class DeviceInput
    {
        public static byte[] PowerArray = { 1, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] InputArray { get; set; }
        public byte[] LEDArray { get; set; }


        public DeviceInput(string name, byte[] input, byte[] led)
        {
            Name = name;
            InputArray = input;
            LEDArray = led;
        }

        public static Dictionary<byte[], string> InputDictionary()
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<byte[], string>();
            dict.Add(PowerArray, "Power Button");

            return dict;
        }

    }
```

And in my main program:

```
public Dictionary<byte[], string> inputDict = DeviceInput.InputDictionary();
```

and in my read method, I take the read-in byte array and store the first 8 bytes into a local array, I use `.ContainsKey()` to see if the Dictionary contains the key (byte array), and then would display the value (string) to the user.

```
byte[] data = 
{ 
    readBuffer[0], readBuffer[1], readBuffer[2], readBuffer[3],
    readBuffer[4], readBuffer[5], readBuffer[6], readBuffer[7]
};

if (inputDict.ContainsKey(data))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You pressed: " + inputDict[data]);
}
```

The readBuffer from the device works just fine, the array is populated perfectly, and is the exact same as the byte array I created (PowerArray), so I'm not sure how `ContainsKey` isn't working. Even when I switch the Dictionary to `<string, byte[]>` and try `ContainsValue` instead of `ContainsKey`, but no success.

Is a Dictionary the best way to have this data? Should I load the data differently? Am I accessing it incorrectly? Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Arrays use the default references equality, so even if they contain values that are equal they will not evaluate as equal.  Just try `array1.Equals(array2);`.  When you create the dictionary you can pass in a `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` that tells it how to compare the keys to handle this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would solve your problems (similar to what @juharr suggested)

```
class PowerArrayEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<byte[]>
{
    public bool Equals(byte[] x, byte[] y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(byte[] obj)
    {
        return obj.Aggregate(0, (current, b) => current ^ b);
    }
}
```

You would use your dictionary in such form:

```
        Dictionary<byte[], string> myDict = 
            new Dictionary<byte[], string>(new PowerArrayEqualityComparer());
```

Or initialize it like this:

```
        var d = new Dictionary<byte[], string>(new PowerArrayEqualityComparer())
        {
            {new byte[] {0, 1, 2, 3}, "Button1"},
            {new byte[] {1, 1, 2, 3}, "Button2"}
        };
```

The only different thing is the inclusion of `PowerArrayEqualityComparer` class in your dictionary's constructor - like this `new PowerArrayEqualityComparer()`, make sure it's there when you initialize your dictionary.

Only this way you can use the `byte[]` as a `TKey` for your dictionaries.

So, below code would from then on, work just fine:

```
        var b = new byte[] {1, 1, 2, 3};
        Debug.WriteLine(d.ContainsKey(b));
```

It would output `True`.